# Проблемы с Drag and Drop в unity c# при изменении разрешения

Tags: c#, unity3d, drag-n-drop

При стандартном разрешении во время перетаскивания объекта все идет хорошо. Но при изменении разрешения в ondrag объект начинает двигаться быстрее курсора, чем выше разрешение тем он быстрее. Вот скрипт перетаскивания объекта и слота(на всякий случай).

```
[HideInInspector]public RectTransform rectTransform;
private Image image;

private void Awake()
    {

        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        image = GetComponent<Image>();
    }
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        image.raycastTarget = false;
    }
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = eventData.delta;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        image.raycastTarget = true;
    }
    Скрипт Слота:
    public class Slots : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

        if(eventData.pointerDrag != null)
        {
            eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В методе OnDrag rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta;*

Comment: Во первых `eventData.delta` это не позиция. Во вторых `eventData` и ваш объект исчесляется в разных системах координат, `eventData` экрана/окна, а объект в системе координат родительского объекта.